# Returns the first index where the specified value appears in the collection

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, dictionary

I'm struggling to retrieve the City index from my code below.

My full code is

Class Country:

```
import UIKit

class Country { 
    var name: String 
    var cities: [City]

    init(name:String, cities:[City]) {
        self.name = name
        self.cities = cities
    }
}
```

Class City:

```
import UIKit

class City { 
    var name: String 

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryLbl: UILabel!

    var countries = [Country]()
    let states = ["CA","GA","FL","NY","NV","TX"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        countries.append(Country(name: "UK", cities: [City(name: "London"),City(name: "Manchester"), City(name: "Bristol")]))
        countries.append(Country(name: "USA", cities: [City(name: "New York"),City(name: "Chicago")]))
        countries.append(Country(name: "China", cities: [City(name: "Beijing"),City(name: "Shanghai"), City(name: "Shenzhen"), City(name: "Hong Kong")]))

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // For the constant "states" I can use firstIndex to retrieve state index
        let stateIndex = states.firstIndex(of: "NY")
        print("This is the retrieved State index \(stateIndex)")
        // Print above shows "This is the retrieved State index Optional(3)" that is right

        // Retrieve City index
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return countries.count
        } else  {
            let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return countries[selectedCountry].cities.count
        } 
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return countries[row].name
        } else {
            let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return countries[selectedCountry].cities[row].name
        } 
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents

        let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedCity = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let cityR = countries[selectedCountry].cities[selectedCity].name

        countryLbl.text = "The right answer was: \(selectedCountry) in \(cityR)"

    }
}
```

As you see, for a regular constant it works as expected.

I new need to do the same for the City. I need, for a specific State, retrieve the City index.
The issue is that, as I built it based in templates and classes, I cannot use firstIndex to locate City Index.

How could I do that? For example, how do I retrieve "Chicago" index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you need the index of country that contains the city, in which case this will work

```
func index(of city: String, in countries: [Country]) -> Int? {
   countries.firstIndex{$0.cities.contains{$0.name == city}}
}
```

and then to use it

```
let indexOfCountryWithCity = index(of: "Chicago", in: countries)
```

or if you want the index of the city in the country's cities array, in which case you will need to add a second step

```
func index(of city: String, in countries: [Country]) -> (countryIndex: Int?, cityIndex: Int?) {
   guard let countryIndex = countries.firstIndex(where: {$0.cities.contains{$0.name == city}}) 
         else {return (nil, nil)}
   let cityIndex = countries[countryIndex].cities.firstIndex{$0.name == city}
   return (countryIndex, cityIndex)
}
```

and the method will now return a tuple with both the index of the `country` in the `countries` array and the index of the `city` in that country's `cities` array.

Usage is:

```
if let result = index(of: "Chicago", in: countries), let countryIndex = result.countryIndex, let cityIndex result.cityIndex {
   //do something with countryIndex & cityIndex
}
```

Note that the returned value will be optionals to cope with the city not existing, and therefore needed unwrapping above.

**UPDATE due to Question being clarified.  The need is to obtain the cityIndex & countryIndex having been provided with country and city names**

```
func indexOf(city: String, inCountry country: String, in countries: [Country]) -> (countryIndex: Int, cityIndex: Int)? {
   guard let countryIndex = countries.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == country}), let cityIndex = countries[countryIndex].cities.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == city}) else {return nil}
   return (countryIndex, cityIndex)
}
```

note that the tuple is now optional, rather than it's fields, so it's easier to unwrap:

```
if let indexes = indexOf(city: "Bristol", inCountry: "UK", in: countries) {
  //do something with indexes.countryIndex and indexes.cityIndex
}
```

Comment: You could also make city conform to Equatable based on its name string, and then you could check if the city instance equals the required string

Comment: Hi flanker.. thanks for your suggestion...
I really liked the possibility to retrieve both Country and City index...
I have added that function to my code but, when I call it, I just get "0".

Func call

        let result = index(of: "Hong Kong", in: [Country(name: "China", cities: [City(name: "Hong Kong")])])
        print("This is the result \(result)")

and the result is 

This is the result (countryIndex: Optional(0), cityIndex: Optional(0))

i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (sorry for the very basic question)

Comment: @AndréFernandes It looks like you passing in a single country array, rather than the array of all the countries.  I'll update my answer with how to use the functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @flanker. I'll test it tonigh. Just for you to know what I'm trying to achive... I have a database with companies addresses (Country and City). I'll read this database and read its Country and City (that are stored as text - country name and city name) - for a specific city. With that info in hands, I need to find the corresponding Country and City index to set the UIPicker in the user interface. There might be cases where the same City name might be in different Countries.

Comment: That's why I'm also using Country as a key. My code provides the Country name and City name and I receive Country Index and City Index for that specific Country... 

Not sure if that helps or if I added confusion instead :-)

Comment: @AndréFernandes  added to my answer to reflect the refined requirements.  Been a quiet day!

Comment: That is perfect @flanker!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve is

```swift
guard let countryUSA = countries.filter({ $0.name == "USA"}).first else { return }
let cityIndex = countryUSA.cities.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Chicago" })
```

Also you can pass the country and city name as variable, instead of explicitly saying `USA` or `Chicago`